# C++ "heap corruption detected" when # of variables declared in .h is > some value

Tags: variables, heap-memory, header-files, variable-declaration, heap-corruption

I am writing an addon to an old, complicated program. I don't think I can paste the code due to size and copyright, but the problem seems general enough:

If I add more variable declarations in my .h file, I get this error when my class is destructor'd:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: (filename of exe goes here)
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#117328) at 0x05260768.
>   CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

I already have a certain number of variables declared (about 85). If I add on exactly two more, it will always give the error message just after the destructor is called.

It doesn't matter if I add two ints, or an array of two ints, or an int and a VrGrLine*. Two more variables declared = heap corruption error on destruction.

Could it be that there is some sort of limit on how many variables you can declare? Can you think of any way this problem could occur?

Thanks for reading!  ( :

Comment: No.   It is extremely unlikely there is a limit on the number of variables.  More likely, you are unwittingly writing past the end of an array somewhere.

Comment: Someone is probably misusing a pointer somewhere and these fields might just push the write far enough that an error was detected.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I thought it might be something like that. I will follow up on your ideas.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "_push the write far enough that an error was detected_"?  Here's my fuzzy interpretation: The array/pointer overrun error was always there, but the extra variables shifted some memory somewhere and now the error is in a place where it is detectable. Somehow the stack variables are moving the heap variables?